# shnayim mikra on succos for Parshas Breishis

Tags: halacha, sukkot, parashat-bereishit, shnayim-mikra

Can you say Shnayim Mikra for Parshas Breishis prior to Simchas Torah?

Comment: Exactly what I was worried about.  I guess we can say it on Friday and Shabbos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked my Rav this night and he told that we have to do it Friday pm (I live in France so 2 days of Yom Tov) after the reading of Vezoth Haberakha.

H'ag Sameah'

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Who is your Rav?

Answer (score 4):

The [Mishnah Acharonah](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50327&st=&pgnum=307) says that one may start immediately after the Chosson Braishis has read his portion.

That seems to be one source on which allced's Rov might have relied.

I now found in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shnayim_mikra_ve-echad_targum):

> On the day of Hoshana Rabbah (any part of the daytime), Shnayim mikra
>   ve-echad targum should be read for the V'Zot HaBerachah portion.

which is a leniency. I did not find the original source.

Asked an OR tonight, 12 Sep 13. He says you can start right after the end of the reading for the Chosson Torah i.e. while the Reader is saying the "Reshus" for the Chosson Braishis.

Comment: "One may start immediately after the Chosson Braishis has read his portion. " That's the same Psak I got from my Rov, HaRav D.A. Morgenstern שליט"א of Ramat Shlomo Jerusalem.