# being maavir sedrah before its being read on shabbat afternoon

Tags: halacha

What is the specific halachic source, if any that says that one should not begin being maavir sedrah until that sedrah has already been lained the previous Shabbos.

Comment: Are these questions related?

Comment: With regards to your first question: Last line on [Brachos 8a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=8&format=pdf) to 8B. See Ein Mishpat there for where this is brought in Rambam and Shulchan Aruch

Comment: As @DoubleAA mentioned, this seems like two separate questions. perhaps you should ask the second part as a different question

Comment: I seem to recall part 2 raised already on this site.

Comment: Part 2 is at http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3084/shnayim-mikra-on-succos-for-parshas-breishis and the answer is the same as I reference below.

Answer (score 1):

[O. Ch. 285 (3) [7]](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50327&st=&pgnum=306). The Mishnah Berurah quotes the Shulchan Oruch who says that one may start from Sunday and says "since we begin reading the next week's sedrah at minchah on Shabbos, someone who is maavir sedrah from then on (after minchah)" does the mitzvah and the text of the Shulchan Oruch is "laav davka".

Comment: The Mishna Berura isn't clear it means after mincha - it could mean after the _time_ of mincha, as the phrase מן המנחה ולמעלה often means (see shaar hatziun there).